# Area chart with two data points. Full width

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I got problems with an area chart to full the entire width when I have two datapoints. Here's a js-fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/user1572526/dG2s5/1/

It has something to do with the min and max value on the xAxis.

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['2013', '2030'],
    min: 0.5,
    max: 1.5
},
```

I'm reading the docs but I cant figure out how to use theese when they are applied on the xAxis since I don't have any number values here. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.min

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not related to min/max

Its related point placement with respect to tick

in plotOptions > area you have pointPlacement.

```
pointPlacement: null //default
pointPlacement: 'on' // on the tick
pointPlacement: 'between' //between the ticks
```

Updated your fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/dG2s5/2/

I hope this is what you are looking for.